# Multiple IMAP connections for multiple users

Tags: email, smtp, imap, gmail-api, gmail-imap

I am looking to build a CRM and I need to be syncing the emails of multiple users. So, my question is how can I manage multiple connections. I see that we can use IMAP IDLE for a single user to get notifications when an email arrives but I will be needing to have hundreds of connections, will just having hundreds of connections in different threads work? Also, I doubt that the email servers will allow that many connections from a single IP.
Also, regarding GMAIL, they provide a REST API but they too have a limit for the maximum number of connections allowed. So, how can I sync emails for all my users?

It would be great if you could point me in the right direction. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hundreds of IMAP connections from a single IP address is not uncommon; there are many offices where the outbound gateway for the entire office network looks like (and really is) a single IP address from the outside.

The challenge is mainly keeping track of this many connections from your code.

IDLE is probably a good idea here, but for your code to be resilient against network outages, you have to be prepared for the IDLE session to be intermittently disconnected, too. So just build your program to reconnect if necessary. Then if you find that you have more connections than your server can handle, changing the code to always, or periodically, disconnect them will be a relatively simple change.

For comparison, think about the number of connections that a busy web server has to manage. And those are *busy* connections; yours will be sleeping most of the time. (Still, you probably have to be careful if you expect to be scaling into tens of thousands of concurrent connections; the OS has a limit which can probably be tweaked up, but not infinitely.)

Comment: Hmm, googling for a bit I suppose you could sustain hundreds of thousands of outbound TCP connections on a single server if they are not all to the same remote and you have enough memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, basically there is no issue in having that many connections but I need to make sure that the system can handle that many connections and re connect if any connection gets disconnected. 
Well, do you know about any open source project doing this so I can have a reference?

Comment: There are a few Python IMAP IDLE solutions but I have not had the time to play around with them. Alas, the standard `imaplib` still lacks the support. This should be the sort of thing that Twisted excels at though the learning curve is allegedly substantial.

Comment: I was going through twisted.mail but it doesn't seem to support IDLE.

Comment: Twisted is slightly less attractive now that Python itself has `async`, but it is a mature package wth many well-tested add-ons. Here is one attempt at IDLE in Twisted but I it seems to be very old: https://jdb.github.io/imap_idle/twisted_imap.html

Comment: I guess I will be using asyncio for now then.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IstUaWa8NBE (Billions of Emails Synced with Python - Nylas Sync Engine).
This video can give you an idea about how it can be done